# styled-components - Parent component style overriding child style

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using `styled-components` with React. I'd like to remove the default bottom margin for all `<p>`s, so in my main `App` component I added a nested selector:

```
const App = styled.div`
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
`
```

However, I do want to be able to add margin to some `<p>`s, e.g.:

```
const SpacedP = styled.p`
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`
```

But when I try to use a `<SpacedP>` within `<App>`, the resulting `App` CSS is more specific than the `SpacedP` CSS, so my `<SpacedP>`s still have no margin! (`App` CSS compiles to `${App} p { ... }`, while `SpacedP` only has one prefix, `${SpacedP} { ... }`).

Is there a common pattern for situations like these? I don't really like the `&&&` specificity workaround suggested [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity), seems ugly and hacky; hoping there's a more common setup that I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: As you said, since the App CSS is more specific, it's normal that its style is applied first. I don't see another solution except the one styled component gives or adding an !important rule.